# How to create a hyperlink side-bar?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have long regretted that browsers don't give any support for navigating a cleanly structured page with nested `<h1>-<h6>` and `<section>`.  So now I have tried to roll [my own](https://perl1liner.sourceforge.io/#DESCRIPTION) (proudly without js, which works surprisingly well, except menu stays displayed until mouse-out).  I have 3 goals:

1. visualize the nested structure – done with the blue left borders extending from heading to end of `<section>`
2. give them a breadcrumb functionality – done with title attribute, but clumsily nested `<div>` that un-titles content, so it tooltips only on the left side.
3. link the side-bar to bookmark or jump to the heading.  Don't know how to do that.  If I put the `<section>` into an `<a>`, the whole content becomes a hyperlink and for href there seems to be no equivalent to how I undid the title on the content.

How would you achieve this?  Do I need a totally different approach, like putting an empty `<a>` to the left of the `<section>` and through some magic making it as tall?  Also I'd line the same 2 areas, the 5px blue along with the 10px white, which should also have the title and link to make it harder to miss it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats an interesting topic. I'd recommend using an `<a>` tag expanded by an `::before` pseudo element and then use absolute positioning to not make the whole `<section>` an anchor tag. Works well in [this](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/dyMmLVV) example.

---

```css
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 48px;
}
section p:first-letter {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
section::before {
  content: attr(h);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 1;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
section a.border::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<section id="description" h="DESCRIPTION">
  <a class="border" href="#description"></a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore voluptas voluptatem totam sint. Ducimus nulla quam similique quas, officiis vero? Nihil repellat illum corporis atque quis necessitatibus doloribus? Est consequuntur voluptatem quo, expedita molestiae tempore id minima impedit doloribus! Inventore optio laborum aliquam veritatis ad, saepe eum, quae distinctio dicta nulla odit expedita unde corporis perspiciatis eos labore odio eaque nemo cumque velit quos fugiat maiores quis! Tempore magnam, enim consequatur neque autem repellendus dolore possimus architecto facilis eveniet adipisci perspiciatis modi totam pariatur eaque, ad quas earum tempora voluptate recusandae iure impedit non? Dolore hic veritatis sit eum consequuntur incidunt laboriosam mollitia distinctio vero error voluptatibus eos, in aliquam veniam quisquam, placeat illo doloremque aliquid quod velit! Consectetur laboriosam officiis deleniti quod reprehenderit aliquam commodi modi reiciendis laborum impedit saepe repellendus, totam eum ducimus aspernatur, eveniet nisi cupiditate maiores! Consequatur dolorum, sequi ipsam dolores itaque odio mollitia. Quae rerum quos corporis. Numquam, nesciunt. Voluptatum reprehenderit rerum libero magni quae alias obcaecati sunt similique dicta quas, facere unde quam commodi ut error fugiat at itaque eos, excepturi ducimus, odio ab! Dolorem dignissimos, repellat quo explicabo excepturi cumque modi minus dolor autem nesciunt commodi incidunt molestiae, veniam quae labore quis a?</p>
</section>
  <section id="documentation" h="DOCUMENTATION">
  <a class="border" href="#documentation"></a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore voluptas voluptatem totam sint. Ducimus nulla quam similique quas, officiis vero? Nihil repellat illum corporis atque quis necessitatibus doloribus? Est consequuntur voluptatem quo, expedita molestiae tempore id minima impedit doloribus! Inventore optio laborum aliquam veritatis ad, saepe eum, quae distinctio dicta nulla odit expedita unde corporis perspiciatis eos labore odio eaque nemo cumque velit quos fugiat maiores quis! Tempore magnam, enim consequatur neque autem repellendus dolore possimus architecto facilis eveniet adipisci perspiciatis modi totam pariatur eaque, ad quas earum tempora voluptate recusandae iure impedit non? Dolore hic veritatis sit eum consequuntur incidunt laboriosam mollitia distinctio vero error voluptatibus eos, in aliquam veniam quisquam, placeat illo doloremque aliquid quod velit! Consectetur laboriosam officiis deleniti quod reprehenderit aliquam commodi modi reiciendis laborum impedit saepe repellendus, totam eum ducimus aspernatur, eveniet nisi cupiditate maiores! Consequatur dolorum, sequi ipsam dolores itaque odio mollitia. Quae rerum quos corporis. Numquam, nesciunt. Voluptatum reprehenderit rerum libero magni quae alias obcaecati sunt similique dicta quas, facere unde quam commodi ut error fugiat at itaque eos, excepturi ducimus, odio ab! Dolorem dignissimos, repellat quo explicabo excepturi cumque modi minus dolor autem nesciunt commodi incidunt molestiae, veniam quae labore quis a?</p>
    <section id="options" h="Options">
  <a class="border" href="#options"></a>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore voluptas voluptatem totam sint. Ducimus nulla quam similique quas, officiis vero? Nihil repellat illum corporis atque quis necessitatibus doloribus? Est consequuntur voluptatem quo, expedita molestiae tempore id minima impedit doloribus! Inventore optio laborum aliquam veritatis ad, saepe eum, quae distinctio dicta nulla odit expedita unde corporis perspiciatis eos labore odio eaque nemo cumque velit quos fugiat maiores quis! Tempore magnam, enim consequatur neque autem repellendus dolore possimus architecto facilis eveniet adipisci perspiciatis modi totam pariatur eaque, ad quas earum tempora voluptate recusandae iure impedit non? Dolore hic veritatis sit eum consequuntur incidunt laboriosam mollitia distinctio vero error voluptatibus eos, in aliquam veniam quisquam, placeat illo doloremque aliquid quod velit! Consectetur laboriosam officiis deleniti quod reprehenderit aliquam commodi modi reiciendis laborum impedit saepe repellendus, totam eum ducimus aspernatur, eveniet nisi cupiditate maiores! Consequatur dolorum, sequi ipsam dolores itaque odio mollitia. Quae rerum quos corporis. Numquam, nesciunt. Voluptatum reprehenderit rerum libero magni quae alias obcaecati sunt similique dicta quas, facere unde quam commodi ut error fugiat at itaque eos, excepturi ducimus, odio ab! Dolorem dignissimos, repellat quo explicabo excepturi cumque modi minus dolor autem nesciunt commodi incidunt molestiae, veniam quae labore quis a?</p>
</section>
</section>
```

Comment: Here's an enhanced version. https://codepen.io/MrFuze/pen/YzqaoRp

Comment: It was a bit confusing with those fancy on the fly headlines, but I adapted your idea, and it works like a charm – one solution to my 3 goals, which the moderator didn't get, but you understood me perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel. Sorry, I wanted the headlines to still be part of the section and didn't figure any else way :'D. Proud to hear, I could help you!